# Proxy issue on calling express server from react server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

Hey guys i was just working out on Proxy for calling nodejs server from react server, so after adding "proxy": `"http://localhost:5000/"`

to my package.json file in react i was able to redirect to localhost:5000 (which is running my node server) but it seems that Proxy only works with fetch and axios as

```
 axios.get("/api/currentuser")
```

redirects me to localhost:5000
but then when i try this on anchor tag like

```
<li><a href="/auth/google">Login with google</a></li>
```

it doesn't takes me to `localhost:5000`
so is there any way that sometimes working with  tag if i need to stay at `localhost:3000`i should be there and whenever i need i can go to `localhost:5000` ???
cause not for all anchor tag i need to redirect to `localhost:5000`

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6031#issuecomment-459859224) and [react documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development#configuring-the-proxy-manually) you can use the file `setupProxy.js` to redirect requests based on certain criteria to a proxy and it also seems to work for `href` property.

You would have to adapt the example code:

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use('/api', proxy({
    target: 'http://localhost:5000',
    changeOrigin: true,
  }));
};
```

to your requirements. You can use pattern matching on the api paths, so it should not be a problem. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: and what if i need to make this work on production level ??

Comment: Probably the best option is using a real proxy from which you serve the bundled code to redirect your requests just like you are doing in development mode